# How to redirect a Wordpress logout to custom URL

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect, logout

I have scoured the web for the last 45 minutes and still not found a simple description of how to send a user, logging out of WordPress, to a custom URL.

I've come across [this](https://rocketgeek.com/tips-and-tricks/redirecting-wordpress-login-and-logout-urls/);

```
add_filter( 'logout_url', 'my_logout_url' );
    function my_logout_url( $url ) {
       return 'http://yourdomain.com/?a=logout';
    }
```

..but it does not describe where to paste that code. And i am not using a 'members' plugin.

Surely there is just something that can be added to the Theme functions.php file or a edit to general-template.php to specify a URL? I'm not even wanting a different site domain. Just back to the login page would be fine, but I would rather be able to specify an entire custom 'link' somewhere in the code. www.example.com

How/where can I do this?

Many thanks in advance for yor help or advice

Comment: You would past that filter code into your `functions.php` file.

Comment: Thanks @JakeParis

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Basic

I know only 2 hooks when logout happen. This is `logout_url` and `wp_logout`. Usually, I use the `wp_logout` in the next way

```
function your_prefix_redirect() {
    wp_redirect('https://google.com/');
    die;
}
add_action('wp_logout', 'your_prefix_redirect', PHP_INT_MAX);
```

Notice, I specified priority as maximum INT, because some other code may do anything else major while logout happen

### Where to place the code?

You should to try the next ways:

1. Place the code inside the `function.php` into your active theme
2. Create a basic plugin has the code above

I don't know about `function.php`, but inside the plugin the code above working well.

### How to create a Wordpress basic plugin

1. Move to folder `wp-content/plugins`
2. Create a file `your-some-prefix-logout-custom-url.php`
3. Open new file and put in next:

   ```
   <?php
   /*
   Plugin Name: Custom logout URL
   Author: Your_Name
   */

   function your_prefix_redirect() {
       wp_redirect('https://google.com/');
       die;
   }
   add_action('wp_logout', 'your_prefix_redirect', PHP_INT_MAX);
   ```

Activate the new plugin in Wordpress admin panel after you done all actions above. If your plugin isn't show in the plugin list then create any folder in `wp-content/plugins` and move your plugin into new folder.
The comment before the code block is requirement. Read the plugin [handbook](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/the-basics/header-requirements/) if you are interested in this

Comment: And this again is to copy/paste into the Theme functions.php file?

Comment: @Plot64 I updated the answer. Hope this clarify the situation